# Could not re-enable the KeyGaurd once disabled it

Tags: android, android-asynctask, togglebutton, keyguard, screen-lock

I have write below code to toggle the `KeyGaurd` of my android phone using a toggle button. but I am  facing an strange behavior.

- it disables the `keygaurd` successfully but. not re-enabling.

  ```
   btnToggleLock.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

          if (btnToggleLock.isChecked()) {

              toast.cancel();
              toast.setText("Unlocked");
              toast.show();

              Log.i("Unlocked", "If");

              KeyguardManager myKeyGuard = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);

              KeyguardLock myLock = myKeyGuard
                      .newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
              myLock.disableKeyguard();


          } else {

              toast.cancel();
              toast.setText("Locked");
              toast.show();

              KeyguardManager myKeyGuard = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
              KeyguardLock myLock = myKeyGuard
                      .newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
              myLock.reenableKeyguard();

              Log.i("Locked", "else");

          }

      }
  });
  ```
- it disables the `keygaurd` successfully but. not re-enabling.
- I tested it the control is traversing both `if` and as well as  `else`

also I m using android 2.2.1 `motoralla milestone`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you are creating a new Lock (KeyGuardLock) every time the "if" statement executes. You can disable a lock the first time when you create it but you must "reenable" the lock which you disabled in the first place, you cannot create a new one.

The solution is to make the lock outside of the onClickListener. i.e. Take the following code out of the "if" statement and declare it before setting the onClickListener:-

```
KeyguardManager myKeyGuard = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
            KeyguardLock myLock = myKeyGuard
                    .newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
```